# hiding tablerows depended on data in td (numbers) with jquery

Tags: jquery, numbers, hide, html-table

i've got a table and i'd like to hide rows that got a td within it with a value les then 100. 
e.g. my table looks like

```
<table>
<tr><td>key</td><td>value</td></tr>
<tr><td>key1</td><td>30</td></tr>
<tr><td>key2</td><td>60</td></tr>
<tr><td>key3</td><td>90</td></tr>
<tr><td>key4</td><td>200</td></tr>
</table>
```

so in this example the first 3 rows should be hided.
I'm doing this with the :contains with non-numeric values but i not sure it is possible to do it with numbers.

And other option i thought about is giving the td's an attribute with the value of the td and hide them depended on the value of the attribute.

something like

`$('tr td[attr>"100"']).hide();`

but im not sure that is the best way to scritp it since im new to jquery

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('tr td:last-child').each(
    function(){
        if (parseInt($(this).text(),10) <= 100){
             $(this).closest('tr').hide();
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PpaUw/2/).

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`:last-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Ah, so it should. Gosh, I need new spectacles, it seems... =/ Edited in, and thanks! =)

Comment: Yeah, I misread the question; I've updated the code and the linked demo, so now it hides all values less than, or equal to, 100.